# Put a pie chart on the map but it was shown in a wrong position

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to use cartopy to represent some data on the map, but I got a problem and don't have any idea to solve it. The problem is the plot was not shown in the right place. Here is my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

# geological centre of Spain
lon, lat = (-4, 40)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
proj = ccrs.Miller(central_longitude=0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=proj)
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, lw=0.5, edgecolor='gray')
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, lw=0.5, edgecolor='gray')
ax_sub = inset_axes(ax, width=0.4, height=0.4, loc=10, bbox_to_anchor=(lon, lat), bbox_transform=ax.transData)
ax_sub.pie([10, 25, 5, 30, 50, 10], wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'gray','linewidth': 0.25})
ax.set_extent ((-12, 44, 35, 88), ccrs.Miller())
plt.show()
```

and the result is:

[image: spain]

The pie chart should be shown in the center of Spain but shifted to the south.

Some issues also happened when plotting pie charts on the other countries.

Is there anyone who knows anything I missed?

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

# geological centre of Spain
lon, lat = (3.41, 40)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
proj = ccrs.Miller(central_longitude=0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=proj)
ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, lw=0.5, edgecolor='gray')
ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, lw=0.5, edgecolor='gray')
ax_sub = inset_axes(ax, width=0.4, height=0.4, loc=10, bbox_to_anchor=(lon, lat), bbox_transform=ax.transData)
ax_sub.pie([10, 25, 5, 30, 50, 10], wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'gray','linewidth': 0.25})
ax.set_extent((-20, 20, 20, 60), ccrs.Miller()) # (left, right, bottom, top)
plt.show()
```

[image]